# Are methods overridden when methods have the same name but different signatures?

Tags: java, methods, overriding

```
public class Superclass {

   void method(Object a){
   }
}


public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    void method(String a){
    }
}
```

In the class above, method in Superclass has parameter of type Object while Subclass has parameter of type String. String is the subclass of Object. My question is, is method overriden in this case?

Comment: Java 6 onwards have an Override annotation to make the link explicit. If you put (at)Override on the subclass it would say that it was not overridden..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most famous example of confusion caused by the issue you raise involves `equals`:

```
public class Banana {
  private final double weight;
  public boolean equals(Banana that) { return this.weight == that.weight; }
}
```

Many people think this is a valid override of `equals`, but it's actually just another method unrelated to `Object#equals(Object)` and will not be involved in equals comparison.

This is one of known pitfalls of Java's type system so take good care to get it right.

To confuse matters further, you *are* allowed to specialize the return type (the return type is *covariant*):

```
public abstract class FruitTree {
  public abstract Object getFruit();
}
public class BananaTree {
  ...
  @Override public Banana getFruit() { return this.bananas.iterator().next(); }
}
```

Note that the notion of *method signature* does not include the return type. Method signature is the key concept in the mechanism of static (compile-time) method resolution, and each signature is a separate point of dynamic method dispatch.

Answer (score 7):

No, its method overloading. For it to be the method overriding the method signature of the super class method and subclass method should be same. Go through  [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/12/method-overloading-vs-method-overriding.html) blog post to know about these two and their difference in detail

Comment: +1 This is a common source of confusion for people writing `boolean equals(MyClass o);`

Comment: It may be worth noting that you can override with a more specific return type though. Of course generics make all of this interesting too.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, I have seen many do this mistake quite a number of times.

Comment: @JonSkeet There was a bug in Java 6 which allowed overloading by return type using generics. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/with-generics-return-type-is-part-of.html

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, generics need another level of understanding. It did blow my mind...

Comment: for the equals method, I can see the java doc stated it is override, so it confuse me